# Visual Studio saying null when try to run code

Tags: visual-studio

so basically i tried running code in visual studio but it says null and doesn't open command prompt and also says build failed (https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gi5GT.png)

how to run the code with no errors

Comment: What Python extension for VS are you using?

Answer (score 1):

If you have python downloaded, then set the python environment. Click on Add Environment. Then browse to in install location.
This will resolve your issue.
[image: Follow the steps]

[image]

Comment: The path is something like: C:\Users\[user]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\

Answer (score 0):

You should download python separately

Just go to https://www.python.org/downloads/ and get the latest python version, then restart VS

It should work, my friend had same problem and this solved it